# Добавление обработчика события click

Tags: javascript, phonegap

Не вызывается JavaScript функция на событие `click:

```
function showfileload() {
    alert("show");
}
```

Пробовал вызывать следующими способами:

- с помощью `onClick`:

  ```
  <input type="radio" name="ottisk" id="ottisk-1" value="no" onclick="showfileload()" checked="checked">
  <label for="ottisk-1">Нет</label>
  <input type="radio" name="ottisk" id="ottisk-2" value="scan" onclick="showfileload();">
  <label for="ottisk-2">Скан</label>
  <input type="radio" name="ottisk" id="ottisk-3" value="yes" onclick="showfileload();">
  <label for="ottisk-3">Есть</label>
  ```
- С помощью `addEventListener`:

  ```
  $("#ottisk-1").addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
  $("#ottisk-2").addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
  $("#ottisk-3").addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
  $(document).addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
  ```

Результата нет. Если просто `alert()` повесить на то же событие `onClick` - всё работает, а вот так, через функцию, - нет.

В консоли следующие сообщения на эти действия:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
>
> 2(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: showfileload is not defined

Почему функция не определена?

Полный код:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {
            $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        });
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $("#ottisk-1").addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
        $("#ottisk-2").addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
        $("#ottisk-3").addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
        function showfileload() {
            alert("show");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <input type="radio" name="ottisk" id="ottisk-1" value="no" checked="checked">
    <label for="ottisk-1">Нет</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ottisk" id="ottisk-2" value="scan">
    <label for="ottisk-2">Скан</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ottisk" id="ottisk-3" value="yes">
    <label for="ottisk-3">Есть</label>
</body>
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, рабочий пример где видно что это не работает

Comment: Это куски кода из того самого примера.
Сейчас выложу где нить полный код

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/3xCcgl7Ojeyne вот код

Comment: @Skif минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример кода должен быть в самом вопросе, а не где-то на другом сайте. Постарайтесь в следующий раз оформить его самостоятельно. Ещё сходу заметил, что у вас почему-то `<DOCTYPE` вместо `<!DOCTYPE`.

Answer (score 1):

В *PhoneGap* нужно инициализировать приложение после открытия.
Причина, скорее всего, в этом. Скопируйте код ниже и попробуйте запустить.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onLoad, false);

function onLoad() {
    $("#ottisk-1").addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
    $("#ottisk-2").addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
    $("#ottisk-3").addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
}
```

**P.S.** В файле, который вы дали, нет нигде `onclick`.

Comment: Я его убрал, потому как после onClick сделал Listener

Comment: Ошибки нет, но и срабатывания функции тоже нет

Comment: addEventListener, в вашем случае, не нужен, так как: 1. Вы используете jQuery. 2. Вы используете атрибут onclick. Выберите одно из этих вариантов и адаптируйте с deviceready. Если остановитесь на jQuery click() функцию, то deviceready можно заменить `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.

Comment: 1. Метода `addEventListener()` у jQuery-объекта попросту нет, поэтому  свалиться код должен в этот момент (`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addEventListener is not a function`). Видимо, автор покривил душой, а вы добавили в свой ответ эту дьявольскую ошибку. 2. От греха подальше (не очень научно звучит, но всё же) стоит добавить `deviceready`, а уже в нём - `document.ready`. Это никак не связано с мифической (потому что полный пример кода, воспроизводящий проблему, не предоставлен) `Uncaught ReferenceError: showfileload is not defined`, но может уберечь от будущих проблем.

Comment: Научности ради я таки прочитал для чего нужно событие `deviceready`, так что в данном случае можно просто остановиться на `document.ready`.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сделать так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function showfileload() {
        alert("show");
        return false;
    }
    $(function() {
        $("#ottisk-1").on("change", showfileload);
        $("#ottisk-2").on("change", showfileload);
        $("#ottisk-3").on("change", showfileload);
    });
</script>
```

То есть вместо `.addEventLister()` мы используем jQuery метод `.on()`.
Как видите, всё происходит внутри `$(function() { ... });`, то есть код исполняется после загрузки документа. У вас же обработчики не добавлялись к элементам, так как они ещё не были загружены.

Да, и я использовал событие `change`, потому что `click` сработает и при клике на выбранный элемент (кстати, возврат `false` в `showfileload()` не дает сменить выбор).

Вместо `$(function() { ... });` можно еще использовать 
 
`window.onload = function() { ... };`, но `$(function() { ... });` предпочтительней.

Comment: @Regent спасибо. Исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Причина в том, что у вас HTML загружается после того как вы на него вешаете обработчик. К моменту выполнения строки

```
$("#ottisk-1").addEventListener("click", showfileload, false);
```

$("#ottisk-1") неизвестен и клик вешается в никуда.

Вам необходмо либо обернуть содержимое  в функцию

```
$(function() { ваш код здесь })
```

либо перенсти блок  ниже HTML